# Skipping a middleware for a particular route inside a route group in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I Want to skip the middleware for a particular route in a  route group. How can I do this?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'testgroup','middleware' => ['login.oauth']],function (){
    Route :: get('/', 'testController@index');
    Route :: get('/api','testController@apiCall');
});
```

I want to skip the 'login.oauth' middleware for the `Route :: get('/api','testController@apiCall')`

Comment: Put the route outside of the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please keep that testgroup function  must be accessible to all routes and middleware function  to particular(some other route) in the same function**

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'testgroup'], function () {
       Route::group(['middleware' => ['login.oauth'], function() {
        Route :: get('/', 'testController@index');
       });
       Route :: get('/api','testController@apiCall');
    });
```

Comment: I want to have this route in the same group. So that I don't have to change the URL prefix for this particular request.

Comment: Route::group(['prefix' => 'testgroup','middleware' => ['login.oauth'],function (){
Route :: get('/', 'testController@index');
});
});

Comment: i have edited  the condition you can check with that now, hope it will helpful

Answer (score 1):

Just create a second group without the middleware:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'testgroup','middleware' => ['login.oauth']],function (){
    Route :: get('/', 'testController@index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'testgroup'],function (){
    Route :: get('/api','testController@apiCall');
});
```

Comment: You are using the same prefix for both route group. is it allowed to do this?

Comment: Yes it is allowed - laravel will traverse through all groups/prefix's to find the route.